# Dynamic generation of file contents (poor man's proc file)

Tags: c, file, stdout, named-pipes, file-descriptor

I'm trying to make a simple userspace program that dynamically generates file contents when a file is read, much like a virtual filesystem. I know there are programs like FUSE, but they seem a bit heavy for what I want to do.

For example, a simple counter implementation would look like:

```
 $ cat specialFile
 0
 $ cat specialFile
 1
 $ cat specialFile
 2
```

I was thinking that `specialFile` could be a named pipe, but I haven't had much luck. I was also thinking `select` may help here, but I'm not sure how I would use it. Am I missing some fundamental concept?

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                      

int main(void)                                                                                                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    char stdoutEmpty;                                                                                                                                                                                   
    char counter;                                                                                                                                                                                       

    while (1) {                                                                                                                                                                                         
        if (stdoutEmpty = feof(stdout)) { // stdout is never EOF (empty)?                                                                                                                               
            printf("%d\n", counter++);                                                                                                                                                                  
            fflush(stdout);                                                                                                                                                                             
        }                                                                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

Then usage would be something like:

```
shell 1 $ mkfifo testing
shell 1 $ ./main > testing
shell 2 $ cat testing
# should be 0?
shell 2 $ cat testing
# should be 1?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use FUSE. A FIFO will not work, because either your program keeps pushing content to stdout (in which case cat will never stop), or it closes stdout, in which case you obviously can't write to it anymore.